# SQL Server query - convert non aggregated column to columns (instead of sum or count)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with three columns: Name, Year and Cnt.
I want to group all rows by name and display Cnt for each year as a separate column
At the moment I have:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(iif(Year = 2010, Cnt, 0)) [2010],
    SUM(iif(Year = 2011, Cnt, 0)) [2011],
    SUM(iif(Year = 2012, Cnt, 0)) [2012],
    SUM(iif(Year = 2013, Cnt, 0)) [2013],
    SUM(iif(Year = 2014, Cnt, 0)) [2014],
    SUM(iif(Year = 2015, Cnt, 0)) [2015],
    SUM(iif(Year = 2016, Cnt, 0)) [2016]
FROM cte
GROUP BY Name
```

But it seems like extremely ugly solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: You need a `PIVOT` table.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with PIVOT especially if I have to group as well, if you could provide some code to help - I would be (almost) eternally grateful :)

Comment: This is exactly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not have set list of years, you are going to need to use dynamic SQL to create the data driven column list:

```
create table #temp
(
    Name nvarchar(10),
    [Year] int,
    cnt int
)

insert into #temp values ('a',2013,1)
                        ,('b',2013,3)
                        ,('a',2014,5)
                        ,('b',2014,23)
                        ,('a',2015,78)
                        ,('b',2015,6)
                        ,('a',2016,3)
                        ,('b',2016,8)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Year]) 
            FROM #temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Name
                    , [Year]
                    , cnt
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 sum(cnt)
                for [Year] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

go
drop table #temp
```

Comment: As promised - I am now eternally grateful and if you are ever in UK - give me a call and I will buy you a beer :)